# installshield suppress reboot from command line

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

i am using installshield msi project type. in this i am executing msiexec.exe /x[productcode] /qn /norestart - this is generating an error code 1722. can anyone please tell me what does this exactly mean? and how can i counter it?

error 1722 :
There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action [2], location: [3], command: [4]

i'm giving following settings - 
working dir - systemfolder
filename and command line - msiexec.exe /x[ProductCode] /qn /norestart

i have also tried REBOOT=ReallySuppress,REBOOT=S, REBOOT="ReallySuppress".
can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run msiexec as a custom action from within an MSI? You can't do that. The second instance of msiexec is trying to instantiate the mutex, but can't as it's being held by the installation already in progress.

If you're wanting to remove an already installed product as part of your installation, just use [the upgrade table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1722 is a generic error when a custom action encounters an error.

Check whether ur customaction returs zero on success.

Either u can ignore the return value of ur custom action EXE.  or u should make ur custom action to return zero on success.

also try /qb instead of /qn so that u could get the error (if any) occurred from windows installer. and if u got that you could fix it soon and later change it to /qn

Comment: thanks for reply but i already found solution. anyways now i am facing error 2761. "Global Mutex not Initialized". what i am doing is, launching installvalidate - removeexistingproduct - installinitialize actions just after cost finalize action. this error occurs after remove... on installinitialize action. any idea why is it coming?? or what it means?? and how can i resolve it?